# setOnClickListener to a Button Programmatically ERROR

Tags: android, button

I am making a simple GPA calculator for a project, we did it first with xml and now my professor wants it dynamically. I have 4 textviews, 4 edittext and 1 button. Everything works fine and runs, but when I try to setOnClickListener() the program will crash. How can I make the button work programmatically.
Here's what I am trying.

```
     android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    // button
    Button button1 = new Button(this);
    final int button1id = View.generateViewId();
    button1.setId(button1id); // id
    button1.setText("Send Data");
    button1.setLayoutParams(params);
    layout.addView(button1);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(button1id);

    OnClickListener clicks = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(v.getId() == button1id){
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }

        }
    };
```

then when i call this it gives me error.

```
button1.setOnClickListener(clicks);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the error message you're getting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do `findViewById`. Just simple call :

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

This will solve your problem .

Answer (score 0):

No need to call button by id anymore also Change View.OnClickListener to just OnClickListener

```
    android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    // button
    Button button1 = new Button(this);
    final int button1id = View.generateViewId();
    button1.setId(button1id); // id
    button1.setText("Send Data");
    button1.setLayoutParams(params);
    layout.addView(button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(clicks)

    OnClickListener clicks = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(v.getId() == button1id){
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }

        }
    };
```